# Test Token for Outlook Add in - always returns null tags

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get test token validation working for an Outlook office add-in.

Decoded String:
VNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZlYFEfJOeldWBtd3IM=

Encoded String:
%3Cr%3E%3Ct%20aid%3D%22WA900006056%22%20pid%3D%22bd1fedd2-ff5f-4b8e-ac48-c2b47ee0ce91%22%20oid%3D%223DBFC30C-DBE9-419E-A5FB-1DB48BEDEC1B%22%20did%3D%22xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com%22%20et%3D%22Trial%22%20ad%3D%222018-01-12T21%3A58%3A13Z%22%20sd%3D%222018-01-12T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%20te%3D%222018-06-30T02%3A49%3A34Z%22%20test%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%3Cd%3EVNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZlYFEfJOeldWBtd3IM%3D%3C%2Fd%3E%3C%2Fr%3E

No matter what and how I pass this to https://verificationservice.officeapps.live.com/ova/verificationagent.svc/rest/verify?token={token} it just does not return anything with any value populated.

It always return as below.

[Response from Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCQ7i.png)

I am using the test token from this reference .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/add-in-license-schema Is the documentation stale on the string format or am I missing anything? The documentation says 64 bit encoding is not required for Office Add-ins.

Can anyone give me a working test token for Outlook Add in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation works if you include ts (even value 0). Taking your encoded token, decode it, and added "ts=0', and encode (using url encode). I get the following that validates:

https://verificationservice.officeapps.live.com/ova/verificationagent.svc/rest/verify?token=%3Cr%3E%3Ct+aid%3D%22WA900006056%22+pid%3D%22bd1fedd2-ff5f-4b8e-ac48-c2b47ee0ce91%22+oid%3D%223DBFC30C-DBE9-419E-A5FB-1DB48BEDEC1B%22+did%3D%22xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com%22+ts%3D%220%22+et%3D%22Trial%22+ad%3D%222018-01-12T21%3A58%3A13Z%22+sd%3D%222018-01-12T00%3A00%3A00Z%22+te%3D%222018-06-30T02%3A49%3A34Z%22+test%3D%221%22+%2F%3E%3Cd%3EVNNAnf36IrkyUVZlihQJNdUUZlYFEfJOeldWBtd3IM%3D%3C%2Fd%3E%3C%2Fr%3E

The documentation does indeed state that ts is not relevant for office addins and that needs an update. However, the above workaround (including ts) should unblock your testing

Comment: Thanks a lot , that works. Please update the documentation , so that it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/add-in-license-schema and submitted a PR. The live topic will be updated soon. Thanks, lindalu-MSFT (lindalu@microsoft.com) Here is the correction:

**ts**  Integer — representing the total number of users licensed to access this add-in, by this purchaser.

- For add-ins that are site licensed, this value is 0.
- This attribute applies to Office Add-ins. Include it in your code even if ts=0. (**NOTE** Previously, this topic incorrectly stated that **ts** does not apply to Office add-ins.)

Comment: While both this information and your actions are helpful, this doesn't actually answer the question. This would be more appropriate as a comment. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). You could make it into an answer by describing what's needed in order to accomplish what the OP desires (i.e. effectively, quoting the changes you are making).